# Understanding BizTalk flat file schemas

Tags: xsd, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm trying to modify the schema generated by the BizTalk flat file wizard.
It's very complex and I'd rather not spend days getting the wizard to make something workable again.

The input is a complex file consisting of carriage return/line feed delimited records. There's currently a single line with a tag at the front to identify it. They would like to add the ability to accept the current line or another similar line.

I need any number of either of two lines in any order.

I created a definition for the second line after the first.
I then surrounded the two line definitions with a Choice node.
The choice node is set to  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded".
I assumed this would give me any number of blocks of either line:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="2" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>

  <xs:element name="GROS">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="GROS" tag_offset="0" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    ...
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="GRSD">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="GRSD" tag_offset="0" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    ...
  </xs:element>

</xs:choice>
```

It fails on the third line:

```
GROS ...
GRSD ...
GRSD ...
```

Any suggestions? My brain hurts.

Comment: What error do you get?  Where are the CR & LF in the payload?  At the end of every record or is not there on the last one?

Comment: CRLF after every record. It's your bog standard fixed length fixed position data text file. The error is "error BEC2004: Unexpected data found while looking for: '\r\n'"  After trying your suggestion the error has moved to a different place in the stream. I tried the ffdasm utility but it prints the same error visual studio shows and will not let me see any of what it did decode. I'm going to try making up smaller tailored files and see if I can decode what's confusing it

Answer (score 1):

Given a payload that looks like

```
GROS1234567890 CR LF
GRSD1234567890 CR LF
GRSD1234567890 CR LF
```

The following schema will happily parse that by tag and then by positional

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.FlatFileSchema40516683" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.FlatFileSchema40516683" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <groupInfo sequence_number="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:element name="GROS">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="GROS" child_order="postfix" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="Fields">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:element name="Field" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                          <xs:appinfo>
                            <fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" pos_length="5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                          </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                      </xs:element>
                      <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                          <xs:appinfo>
                            <fieldInfo sequence_number="2" justification="left" pos_length="5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                          </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="GRSD">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <recordInfo sequence_number="2" structure="delimited" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" child_order="postfix" tag_name="GRSD" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="Fields">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <recordInfo structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:element name="Field" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                          <xs:appinfo>
                            <fieldInfo sequence_number="1" justification="left" pos_length="5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                          </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                      </xs:element>
                      <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                          <xs:appinfo>
                            <fieldInfo sequence_number="2" justification="left" pos_length="5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                          </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Output

```
<Root xmlns="http://Scratch.FlatFileSchema40516683">
    <GROS xmlns="">
        <Fields>
            <Field>12345</Field>
            <Field2>67890</Field2>
        </Fields>
    </GROS>
    <GRSD xmlns="">
        <Fields>
            <Field>12345</Field>
            <Field2>67890</Field2>
        </Fields>
    </GRSD>
    <GRSD xmlns="">
        <Fields>
            <Field>12345</Field>
            <Field2>67890</Field2>
        </Fields>
    </GRSD>
</Root>
```

The main difference is that I have put a Fields record (positional) below the tagged record (which is delimited by CR LF).

Note, this will only work if all records finish with a CR LF as the delimiter is defined as Postfix (expect the delimiter after it).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: Still having issues. My schema is structured to have logical groups within it and I think that's what's confusing it. Your element named 'Root' is a logical grouping. It's marked as delimited but without a delimiter specified. I copied that to my logical sub divisions. I get warnings 'Child Delimiter Type property is not set for a delimited record". If I set it to positional it just crashes. Is the delimited element expecting delimiter characters after the group? In your schema it would expect an extra return and line feed at the end of the file because 'Root' is marked delimited?

Comment: Flat file schemas are a nightmare. I have an optional grouping of records, with optional groupings within it, and optional groupings within that. I'll try pulling out just that and using the wizard to see what it generates then see if they can be combined into one schema

Comment: @Jay No, my root node it not expecting an extra CR LF at the end.  Can you give a sample file and the schema you have so far?   Sometimes what I do is just start with a very basic schema that all it has is one repeating record and a single field underneath it so that it parses the file.  Then I will add a record above that to parse a specific record type into it's  components.  Verify that works, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get it to work by going at it sideways. I modified the existing node and replaced the record identifying tag with a 'TagIdentifier' string field. That got around the requirement for multiple types of nodes in different combinations. I modified the map to test the content of the string field to determine which type of record was received.

This will only work because the two records are otherwise identical.